# d3 - colour changed after calling function

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and I try to make a stacked/grouped histogram.

I define a global colour definition like this:

```
var c_gender = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["missing", "present"])
    .range(["#54278f", "#DADAEB"]);
```

and I use it to fill the rects (5 rects for 2 variable = 10 rects if grouped and 5 if stacked) in my histogram chart. All works fine but I noticed that the domain of the colour has been changed. I use this color definition in other charts so, the domain is not correct.
After using the colours to modify the style of my rects, more values are added to the domain of the colour like this:

```
var dataset = [
    [
        { x: 0, y: missing_age_array.length },
        { x: 1, y: missing_gender_array.length },
        { x: 2, y: missing_weight_array.length },
        { x: 3, y: missing_height_array.length },
        { x: 4, y: missing_ethnicity_array.length }
    ],
    [
        { x: 0, y: present_age_array.length },
        { x: 1, y: present_gender_array.length },
        { x: 2, y: present_weight_array.length },
        { x: 3, y: present_height_array.length },
        { x: 4, y: present_ethnicity_array.length }
    ]
];


data_stack = d3.layout.stack()(dataset);
...
console.log(c_gender.domain());
var layers = vis.selectAll("layer")
        .data(data_stack)
        .enter().append("g")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return c_gender(i / (n - 1))    ; })
        .attr("class", "layer");
console.log(c_gender.domain());
...
```

and the console.log result is:

```
["missing", "present"]
["missing", "present", 0, 1]
```

I am not sure this explanation is clear.. but can somebody help me to understand why the domain of the color is changed after calling a function?

TYIA
 -monica

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation for ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#_ordinal):

> Given a value x in the input domain, returns the corresponding value in the output range.
>
> If the range was specified explicitly [...] and the given value x is
> not in the scale’s domain, then x is implicitly added to the domain;

By calling `c_gender(i / (n - 1))`, you implicitly add 0 and 1 as values in the domain.

You'll have to rework your scale to match the values you want to use : `i / (n - 1)` can't directly yield `missing` and `present`